# mergEXT AES encryption error

Tags: livecode

I've attempted to use the mergEXT AES iOS extension to encrypt a string in an iOS app, and have a Livecode server script decrypt it, to no avail.  According to the docs on mergEXT,

> The OpenSSL functions use the Salted__ style encrypted data header as OpenSSL generates and is therefore compatible with the encrypt/decrypt with password command available on LiveCode desktop platforms.

I've also tried this on the desktop, with the same results:

(SSL error: wrong final block length)

Sample app code:

```
put mergAESOpenSSLEncrypt(tUsername, "password") into tEncUsername
```

Sample LC Server (and desktop) code:

```
decrypt tEncUsername using "aes-256-cbc" with password "password"
```

Any ideas as to what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: The most likely issue is how the data is being encoded between when it's encrypted and when it's decrypted. LiveCode does some interesting things  particularly when writing to files unless you specifically tell it to write in binary mode. To be safe you might want to do something like base64Encode.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, but I'm not writing it to a file in this example. It is encrypted on user input and sent to the LC script server.  I have attempted both base64 and URL encode/decode, with the same results.  I have also tried copying the encrypted value from the simulator and attempted to decrypt it with a simple desktop stack. Using the built in encrypt produces a visually different result than the extension.

Comment: The next question is probably the encoding before and after encryption and in particular if LC 7 is involved here. There are still a few tweaks going on with the externals sdk for LC 7 but you should encode the password as Mac Roman for the time being.

Comment: Using Livecode 7.0.2 rc2.  Not sure what you mean by the encoding before and after, but here is a bit of sample code to try in a quick iOS app:  `put "beer" into tTemp  
   put mergAESOpenSSLEncrypt(tTemp, "password") into tEncUsername  
   put tEncUsername into fld "out"`    I put this into a button that displays the encoded bit into a field, and get a different result every time.  I must be doing something wrong!

Comment: So I guess it is using a random salt.  I was able to trap an error from the LC server bit, of: `wrong final block length`  Does that shed any light?

Comment: OK, there's a few issues here. In 7.0.2 there were some changes that broke externals. I'm hoping that this will be resolved in RC 3 as there's an open pull request that fixes it.

The other thing is in LC 7 everything is unicode so you need to make sure your strings are encoded mac roman before using them with the external. This should get simpler in future versions where the external sdk will become more compatible. See the textEncode and textDecode functions. Are you using LC 7 for server too?

Comment: Actually, I an using LC 6.x for the server, but I could upgrade if needed.  I tried uniEncode/decode (as that's all that is available in 6x), along with various base64/urlencodes, to no avail.  The encrypt/decrypt of mergAES works fine with as long as it's contained within the app, just not in passing it off to LC server to decrypt.

Comment: so are you textEncode(tUsername,"MacRoman") before encrypting?